# Ajax Mysql Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am propably being a complete idiot and not seeing the big picture here. I am trying to write a little ajax thingie that would pull information from a database but i cant seem to get the thing going ... please tell me what i am doing wrong.

I put the code together by following a couple of online tutorials and i am no ajax genius. my ajax skills could propably start the next world war.

Here is my code. please feel free to tell me im an idiot if i missed something small.

```
     <html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showDetail(str) {
            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    Wallet Number : <input type="text" name="wallet01" id="wallet01"  />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="showDetail(wallet01)">


</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Kit info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('10.1.75.131','markdv','qwerty123','MTNAutomation');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"MTNAutomation");
$sql="SELECT serialNumber FROM Kit_T WHERE serialNumber = '$q'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Wallet Number</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['serialNumber'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: also how would i go about adding a processing gif or something like that just to give an indication to the user that the content is being retrieved / loaded

Comment: @JayBlanchard not getting any errors. The table is shown with the heading but no other information.

Comment: Have you run the PHP by itself to make sure that it returns the table?

Comment: @JayBlanchard just did that now and yes it does return the table and all the correct information, just not getting the input from the ajax function to retrieve the same info

Comment: When you watch the request / response in the browser's console do you see everything come back via the AJAX request?

Comment: Hi you put 'onsubmit="showDetail(wallet01)"', but 'wallet01' is not a javascript variable.

Comment: The default action of submitting a form is to send the form to the action page.  You need to prevent this in your event handler.

Comment: @Jacobi ahh that makes sense. well sort of, how would i go about getting the variable from the input box into the js function.

Comment: with jQuery you can get this way: "$('#submit').val()"; and with pure js, "document.getElementById('submit').value"

Comment: @Jacobi thanks i will go look at how to do that, like i said my Js, Ajax, Jquery knowledge is completely non existant

Comment: I'm changing the answer, to help you more, just a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your HTML. You put 'onsubmit="showDetail(wallet01)"', but 'wallet01' is not a javascript variable.

I would suggest changing it to this:

```
<form onsubmit="return showDetail()">
    Wallet Number : <input type="text" name="wallet01" id="wallet01"  />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I added the "onsubmit" in the form, using the function with "return", to prevent the default submit from form. But remember to always return false in the function.

Than in the function you can get the value for the field.

```
    function showDetail() {
        var str = document.getElementById('wallet01').value;

        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return false;
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        return false;
    }
```

Or you can use the ajax from jQuery, it's easier.
See an example here

```
    function showDetail() {
        var str = $('#wallet01').val();

        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return false;
        }

        var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
                url: "example.php",
                type: "GET", 
                data: {q: str}
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                alert( "success" );
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert( "error" );
            }).always(function( ) {
                alert( "complete" );
            });

        return false;
    }
```

See the [JQuery Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
You also have the function "beforeSend" to start a gif "loading".

Comment: please seend me your address so i can pay you in beer!!! You are a rockstar.. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @Stroes. Wow... Beer will always be good...hahaha. Good to know that it worked for you. :)